# Why kwargs keyword given both as string and not as string in Python?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

This block of very simple code below *requires* that the keyword bird first be presented as a string and then *not* as a string.
In:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    if 'bird' in kwargs:
        print('We roast {} for Thanksgiving'.format(kwargs['bird']))
    else:
        print("We're vegan")
myfunc(bird = 'turkey')
```

Out:

```
We roast turkey for Thanksgiving
```

Why is it that in the *if* statement and *format* argument the word bird must be presented as a string, but later when calling the function (namely, myfunc(bird = ‘turkey’) it must NOT be written as a string? I promise, I have tried to look for an answer to this question before posting here. Thanks for your help!

[image: 1]

Comment: That's just a beneficial quirk of parameter passing.  Ordinarily, you would have `def myfunc(bird):`, and the value would be substituted.  To allow for variable parameter lists, Python will build a dictionary out of the arguments when you  specify `**kwargs`, and dictionaries use strings for keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, Tim! That’s very clear. And thank you for “parameter passing” — I’m happy to learn the lingo.  :)

Comment: "I promise, I have tried to look for an answer to this question before posting here."  Try looking in section 4.7 of the Python tutorial, which is automatically downloaded with every standard Python package from python.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a bit philosophical about it, the ** syntax for parameters straddles the border between two different worlds — the world of the program itself, and the world of the data that the program operates on.

When you use keyword arguments as Tim Roberts writes in a comment, to decide which actual parameter gets matched up with which formal parameter, you are staying firmly in the "program" world. If you have a program that does

```
def myfunc(bird, stone=None):
```

and then call it with

```
myfunc(bird='Turkey')
```

the `bird` name does not really have to exist in the running program. In a compiled language, the compiler could just have remembered "pass Turkey as the first parameter and nothing as the second", and that would have been enough.

However, when you do

```
def myfunc(**kwargs)
```

the `bird` name suddenly jumps across the border from program to data, so we need a way to handle the name `bird` as data. Some languages, like Lisp and PostScript, have special syntax for handling names as data (`'bird` in Lisp, `/bird` in PostScript) but Python chose to simply use strings. It *could* also have required calls to use strings, i.e.

```
myfunc('bird'='Turkey')
```

(this would have allowed things like `myfunc('bi'+'rd'='Turkey')`.)

To know why this wasn't chosen, we'd have to interview Guido, but a decent guess would be "Too much typing and it doesn't really buy anything over using the ** call syntax".